# Pandas styler using 'set_table_styles' along with 'applymap'

Tags: python, pandas

What is the right way of using `applymap` along with pandas `set_table_styles`?
I have below a sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

dict_sample = {'one': [1, 1.2 , 1.3, 2, 4],
    'two': [2.1, 2.2 , 1.3, 1.9, 0.1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_sample)
```

I am styling this using the following CSS

```
styles =   [
    {'selector': 'th',
    'props': [('background', 'skyblue'), 
              ('color', 'white'),
              ('font-family', 'tahoma'),
              ('text-align', 'left') ]},

    {'selector': 'td',
      'props': [('font-family', 'tahoma'),
                ('color', 'black'),
                ('text-align', 'left') ]},

    {'selector': 'tr:nth-of-type(even)',
    'props': [('background', '#bfbfbf'),
              ('font-weight', 'bold'),]}, 

    {'selector': 'tr:nth-of-type(odd)',
    'props': [('background', 'white'),
              ('font-weight', 'bold'),]}, 

    {'selector': 'tr:hover',
    'props': [('background-color', '#bfeaf9')]}
]
```

Below is a pattern which I would be  calling later using `applymap` for custom colouring of values

```
def pattern(value):
  if value < 1:
    color = 'green'
    return 'color: %s' % color
  elif value >= 1 and value < 2:
    color = 'orange'
    return 'color: %s' % color
  else:
    color = 'red'
    return 'color: %s' % color
```

Finally, chaining the styles and calling them

```
(
  df.style.set_caption('Test')
  .set_table_styles(styles) # overwrite=True/False, has no effect
  .hide(axis='index') 
  .applymap(pattern)
)
```

**Problem**

Styling defined in `set_table_styles` is applied but not the colouring mentioned in the `applymap`. If I comment out the `set_table_styles` block then the custom `applymap` works.
Am I missing something here? I think this is somehting trivial but unable to see my mistake.

Comment: Found a not so elegant solution by commenting out the  ` 'selector': 'th`   in styles CSS.

Comment: Look at the pandas documentation for Table Visualisation in particular the CSS hierarchies section. A basic solution is to use `!important` in the applymap styles

Comment: @Attack68: Thanks, the trumpcard ```!important``` did the trick.